# if size_t is 64 bits what is the maximum size of a char array?

Tags: c, memory, out-of-memory, size-t

I've seen several answers that come close to this but not a specific answer.

If size_t is set to 64 bits then 2^64 is approximately 18 quintillion standard chars (usually bytes) as the maximum size for a char* array. If divide by 10^9 (GB) we end up with **18GB** as the maximum theoretical (and if its possible to buy a laptop with 32GB - then also real) limit to the size of an array in memory.

Is 18GB really a limit for char arrays/strings on 64 bit machines or have I missed something in my reasoning?

I'm doing my first true CS course so please excuse me if I have got anything seriously wrong with my understanding.

EDIT
For anyone reading this it would appear my maths is wrong so make sure to read the answers below. Specifically when I divided by 10^9 this converted the answer into GB units but there was still 18 * 10^9 of those GB. Which is equivalent to 18 Exabytes.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to get a new calculator. Check `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: (2^64 addresses)/(10^9 addresses/GB) = 1.8e10 GB... You have a maximum of 18 trillion **gigabytes** of storage, not 18 trillion bytes. That equals 18 exabytes. Always check your units!

Comment: [According to Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=2%5E64+bytes+in+gibibytes) 2^64 bytes = 17179869184 gibibytes. As @Olaf said, `SIZE_MAX` determines the maximum value of a `size_t`. Also, in C a `char` is always a byte. The name is just a historical misfortune.

Comment: @Kninnug: Just to add that a bytes might have more than 8 bits.

Comment: @Olaf good point, though that's (for now) uncommon in laptops.

Comment: @Kninnug: If they had widenth a byte, we could have longer worked wit 32 bit machines and Win XP. No one needs 64 bits! ;-)

Comment: "*I've seen several answers that come close to this but not a specific answer.*" -- How is [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32747833/827263) not specific enough?

Comment: @Olaf I'm completely in favor of 256-bit bytes: let's skip the intermediaries and be future-proof till the end of the universe and the next! (and to mess with anything that assumes the value of `CHAR_BIT` can fit in 8 bits :P).

Comment: Im sorry @KeithThompson your answer is excellent it was just that Eriks answer was the one that actually helped me to click on where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math is wrong.  Yes, 2^64 is about 18 quintillion addresses... but you went wrong dividing by 10^9.  You don't have 18 gigabytes of addresses, you have 18 billion gigaBytes - 18 quintillion addresses, as you noted at the start.

16 bits is 64K; 32 bits is 4 GB; 64 bits is 16 exabytes.

Comment: ah it was just poor mathematics on my part.

Answer (score 2):

If `size_t` is 64 bits, then (assuming no padding bits) `SIZE_MAX` is 2<sup>64</sup>-1, or 18446744073709551615. That's a bit over 18 *exabytes*, or about 17 billion gigabytes.

(It's 17 rather than 18 because, in this context, the prefixes "kilo", "mega", "giga", et al represent powers of 1024, not of 1000. In recent years, [binary prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) have been introduced that unambigously represent powers of 1024, but they haven't seen widespread use.)

Yes, that means that 2<sup>64</sup>-1 is *an* upper bound for the size of any object your program can create. (There's some ambiguity in the standard, but the intent is that `size_t` can represent the size of any object.)

That doesn't mean you can actually create an object that big. 2<sup>64</sup>-1 is *an* upper bound on the size of an object, but not (necessarily) the *least* upper bound. In practice, other considerations, such as the amount of available memory (physical and/or virtual) and machine addressing limitations, will usually impose much smaller limits.

On a system with a 32-bit `size_t`, the maximum theoretical object size is about 4 gigabytes, and on modern systems that could be an actual limit. With a 64-bit `size_t`, given modern computer technology, the actual limit is almost certainly going to be imposed by something else.

Answer (score 1):

1 GB = 2^30 or about 10^9

So 2^64 in GB is 2^(64-30) = 2^34 = 17,179,869,184GB ... 18 GGB "eighteen giga-gigabytes" ;)